# Stop ApplicationDbContext creating a database

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there some way I can just stop in a .NET 4.5, MVC5 application the ApplicationDbContext from creating the **authentication** database for me. I'm on shared hosting so it's not an option.

Right now I'm quite happy to have two database's running, one for production and one for authentication, I will get back to sorting that out later. For now I need to be working on SEO and put the authentication database up manually.

I'm guessing it would mean re-writing this code?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

The site is ready to go bar this issue, can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Kind of tricked it, as long as you use the same database name it wont try and re-create it and it's all working now. SEO it is now!